# OBD2 not showing up under Bluetooth devices

Tags: obd-ii, bluetooth

When plugged into one car it shows up but in the other one it doesn't. So I know the obd2 itself scanner is not dead. In the working vehicle all functions are working.

works in 2005 Porsche Cayenne. Doesn't show up in Bluetooth in 2012 Nissan 370Z.

I'm using the same android phone to test in both cases.

**Update**

I tried with another OBD2 device that I know works (because it works in a 3rd car), and it did not work.

So, I guess the OBD2 port is dead.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you tried other devices on the Nissan to see if it's readable there?

Comment: Some cars are very particular which devices they will communicate with, with some they won’t at all...

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2, great idea. I forgot I have another device! I'll try that and update my question with the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In some models of the 370Z, there is a transport / storage switch in the interior fuse box. It's meant to reduce battery drain when the car is not being used by a driver. It cuts power to the obd2 among other things but not anything vital so you wouldn't notice it from daily driving.

[image]

When I was checking fuses earlier, I had pulled out this switch just a little and not pushed it back in all the way. Once that was pushed in, the Bluetooth obd2 device was detected properly.